# check the first login for specific roles

Tags: css, login, user-roles, count, authentication

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50183646/check-the-first-login-wordpress) answer i created a small functionality for users that are logging in for *the first 3 times* to make some elements classes use css animation. What i am trying to do is to adjust this code to count and control the first 3 times of **all user roles** except **subscribers**.

Basically i need this functionality to start counting the first login by user role. Lets say the first time a contributor login, or an editor, or better **all user roles** except **subscribers**

Here is my code so far

```
add_action( 'wp_login', 'track_user_logins', 10, 2 );
function track_user_logins( $user_login, $user ){
    if( $login_amount = get_user_meta( $user->id, 'login_amount', true ) ){
        // They've Logged In Before, increment existing total by 1
        update_user_meta( $user->id, 'login_amount', ++$login_amount );
    } else {
        // First Login, set it to 1
        update_user_meta( $user->id, 'login_amount', 1 );
    }
}

add_action('wp_head', 'notificationcss');
function notificationcss{
    if ( !current_user_can('subscriber') ) {
        // Get current total amount of logins (should be at least 1)
        $login_amount = get_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), 'login_amount', true );

        // return content based on how many times they've logged in.
        if( $login_amount <= 3 ){
            echo '<style>.create-post {animation: pulse-blue 2s 7;} .bb-header-icon.logged-in-user.element-toggle.only-mobile img{animation: pulse-red 2s 7;} </style>';
        } else {
            echo '<style>.create-post {animation: none;} .bb-header-icon.logged-in-user.element-toggle.only-mobile img{animation: none;} </style>';
        }
    }
}
```

How could i manipulate the *track_user_logins* function to count the login times for all roles except subscribers. The existing function counts all users.

*Example: A user is registered in the site for the first time with role *Subscriber*. After some login times(lets say 7-8), his role is being changes to *Contributor*. From that first time logged in as a Contributor the *track_user_logins* should start counting.*

Any ideas would be gladly appreciated.

Comment: You have `if ( !current_user_can('subscriber') ) {` in your code. Does that not work?

Comment: @JacobPeattie thanks for the reply. This **if** is just for keeping the css classes with animation for all non subscriber roles. But doesn't actually ''count'' the login times a non subscriber has been logged in. So what i need is to change the _track_user_logins_ function to count accordingly to user role.

Comment: Can't you just add the same condition?

Comment: @JacobPeattie not really sure how

Answer (score 0):

You've already got the condition you need in your `notificationcss()` function, so just add the exact same code to `track_user_logins()`:

```
function track_user_logins( $user_login, $user ){
    if ( !current_user_can('subscriber') ) {
        if( $login_amount = get_user_meta( $user->id, 'login_amount', true ) ){
            // They've Logged In Before, increment existing total by 1
            update_user_meta( $user->id, 'login_amount', ++$login_amount );
        } else {
            // First Login, set it to 1
            update_user_meta( $user->id, 'login_amount', 1 );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks @JacobPeattie i will try that and give a feedback

Comment: i tested but doesn't seems to work. i made the following example.

A user is registered in the site for the first time with role Subscriber. After some login times(lets say 7-8), his role is being changed to Contributor. From that first time logged in as a Contributor i should get an animation response on those classes. For the first, second and third loggin time. 

I dont get the animation. Although this seems to work for already existing 'non subscriber' users, it didn't work for a new user. Any idea?

Comment: as it seems it doesn't actually start counting for all 'non subscriber' users. I made another test. Created a user with Subscriber default user role. 1 attempt to login as Subscriber, -switched roles- 2nd attempt to login as 'Contributor' , can see the animation. 3d attempt to login as 'Contributor', can see the animation. 4d attempt to login as 'Contributor', can not see the animation. (But i should be able to see it since i set `$login_amount <= 3`)

Answer (score 0):

Made it working. The correct condition would be

```
add_action( 'wp_login', 'track_user_logins', 10, 2 );
function track_user_logins( $user_login, $user ){
    if ( user_can( $user->id, 'edit_posts' )) {
        if( $login_amount = get_user_meta( $user->id, 'login_amount', true ) ){
            // They've Logged In Before, increment existing total by 1
            update_user_meta( $user->id, 'login_amount', ++$login_amount );
        } else {
            // First Login, set it to 1
            update_user_meta( $user->id, 'login_amount', 1 );
        }
    }
}
```

with *user_can( $user->id, 'edit_posts' )* can check the role of the logged in user.